# Non editable custom taxonomy

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I have reviewed [Creating a non-removable taxonomy term](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158784/creating-a-non-removable-taxonomy-term) but it has not answered my question.

One of the built-in Taxonomy terms is the "post formats". This cannot be edited. What I would like to do is register a taxonomy for which my plugin will provide the terms that, likewise, cannot be edited. How do I do this? Is it possible to hook whatever in core keeps the format taxonomy locked down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing [register_taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy), set the `public` parameter of the `args` argument to false.

Most basic example:

```
register_taxonomy( 'my_tax, 'post', [ 'public' => false ] );
```