# How to create a non removable taxonomy term?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I have [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158784/creating-a-non-removable-taxonomy-term) question but it refers to frontend

How can make an unremovable term in the backend similar to uncategorized? 
Thought it could be renamable I believe the slug or ID will remain the same. 
I have a custom taxonomy.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

To make unremovable terms, you need to revoke the delete link appear on the terms screen. 
To revoke terms delete link, you can use 
filter: manage_TAXONOMY_COLUMN.